# Showing $n^{\lfloor \log B\rfloor+ \frac{1}{2}(\log^4(n)+\log^2(n))}< n^{\log^4(n)}$, where $B=\lceil \log^5 (n)\rceil$ and $n>2$

Tags: inequality

I am trying to understand why $$n^{\lfloor \log B\rfloor+ \frac{1}{2}(\log_2^4(n)+\log_2^2(n))}< n^{\log_2^4(n)}$$ where $B=\lceil \log_2^5 (n)\rceil$ and $n>2$.
Any hint would be precious!

Comment: If $n\gt2$, then we can take the log and divide by $\log(n)$. Are you assuming $n\in\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: I am assuming n natural number.

Comment: So $n\ge3$. That's good, because when $2\lt n\lt e$, I don't think this is true. I think my previous comment should work,

Comment: I am really sorry, I forgot to say that the log is in base 2

Comment: Ok, that is usually written either as $\log_2(n)$ or $\lg(n)$; however, if you state that the logs are base $2$, then all is good. Still my prior suggestion should work.

Comment: This doesn't seem to hold for $n=3$; though, it does hold for $n\ge4$.